# jQuery Globalize plugin - get localized format/change format - not working as expected

Tags: jquery, globalization, jquery-globalization

I am trying to convert a float from one culture to another, and seems nothing i found online was working for me. The problem is:

1. I have a parameter coming from external resource (web service) in a specific culture.
2. the result is send to an MVC application, and VALIDATED depending on the current culture settings.

this means i have to somehow convert from the static culture ("en-US") to whatever is selected ON THE CLIENT, before the data is sent to the server for processing, so all the data from the client is on one culture.

I believed that Globalization jQuery plugin ([GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)) will provide this functionality for formatting numbers (and dates) in given culture out-of-the-box, but it seems it do not.

What i tried: 
using the Globalization plugin, setting `Globalize.culture` property, and hoping that `Globalize.format(Globalize.parseFloat("1.2435677777", 10, "en-US")))` will format the value with the desired decimal separator. However it seems it does not worked for me.

If anyone can point what i did wrong, and give a better working example - will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Globalize.format() function always returns a '.' decimal separator, as far as i understood, there is a little hacky solution, but at least it works. 
The point is at replacing the 'neutral' decimal separator with that for the current culture

```
Globalize.parseFloat("1.2435677777", 10, "en-US").toString().replace(".", Globalize.cultures[Globalize.cultureSelector].numberFormat["."])
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if i specify a format for the format function.

```
Globalize.culture("sv");
Globalize.format(Globalize.parseFloat("1.2435677777", 10, "en-US"), "N");
```

Gives: '1,24'